# logcat not generating while device in sleep mode in android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat

when we run an application we can debug using logcat in eclipse/android studio but if we install apk in device we don't know what is happening for that we can generate log file programatically and save it in device.

This is the code i used for generating log :

```
String fileName = "logcat"+".doc";
    File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"/"+fileName);
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f "+outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is all working fine but my question is :

when app is running in background(service is continuously running) if device goes to sleep after certain time log generating is stopped but app is running in the background.

I don't know how to fix the problem, could anyone help me?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use adb logcat? Within Android Studio/Eclipse? Or even on command line with USB Debugging?

Comment: thanks for reply @Demortes.  we can't test all the time using adb logcat but  some times when we install apk and unexpectedly we get some exceptions which we can not produce again right for like those exceptions i think it may useful.

Comment: I'd look at integrating a different solution. Primarily something like Splunk's MINT or even run it through TestFairy or HockeyApp. Once a device goes to sleep, it should run things like onPause() and so on, but Android has final say if that even runs.